# Uniqueness index by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by

I have a dataframe that basically looks like :

```
A=pd.DataFrame({'Id':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2],'Time'[0,0.5,1.2,1.2,0.2,0.2,0.5]})
idx Id  Time
0   1   0.0
1   1   0.5
2   1   1.2
3   1   1.2
4   2   0.2
5   2   0.2
6   2   0.5
7   3   1.7
```

and I would like to assign an time-ordering index to the different values of Time **for each Id**. So basically this columns should give the order to the Time value for this specific Id. Furthermore, entries with same Id and same Time should have the same ordering index. I should then have :

```
idx Id  Time Time_order
0   1   0.0  0
1   1   0.5  1
2   1   1.2  2
3   1   1.2  2
4   2   0.2  0
5   2   0.2  0
6   2   0.5  1
7   3   1.7  0
```

How can I do that efficiently without for-loops ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `groupby` with `rank` using `method='dense'`

```
A.assign(Time_order=A.groupby('Id').Time.rank(method='dense') - 1)

   idx  Id  Time  Time_order
0    0   1   0.0         0.0
1    1   1   0.5         1.0
2    2   1   1.2         2.0
3    3   1   1.2         2.0
4    4   2   0.2         0.0
5    5   2   0.2         0.0
6    6   2   0.5         1.0
7    7   3   1.7         0.0
```

---

`astype(int)` if you really want to

```
A.assign(Time_order=A.groupby('Id').Time.rank(method='dense').astype(int) - 1)

   idx  Id  Time  Time_order
0    0   1   0.0           0
1    1   1   0.5           1
2    2   1   1.2           2
3    3   1   1.2           2
4    4   2   0.2           0
5    5   2   0.2           0
6    6   2   0.5           1
7    7   3   1.7           0
```

---

#### `pd.factorize`

```
A.assign(Time_order=A.groupby('Id').Time.transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x, sort=True)[0]))

   idx  Id  Time  Time_order
0    0   1   0.0         0.0
1    1   1   0.5         1.0
2    2   1   1.2         2.0
3    3   1   1.2         2.0
4    4   2   0.2         0.0
5    5   2   0.2         0.0
6    6   2   0.5         1.0
7    7   3   1.7         0.0
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks a lot !